# How to make hyperlink if the bean property contains http?

Tags: java, jsp, struts

In my application i have developed a message board where end users can post messages and can get replies. If the message(commentText) contains any links to websites i need to display them as hyperlinks. How to achieve this ? I am using struts 1.3.

The JSP code:

```
<tr>
    <td width="8%">
    <span class="formlabel">
              <bean:message key="ui.jsp.dashboard.news.showNews.message" />
    </span>
    </td>
    <td width="80%">
       :&nbsp;&nbsp;<a><bean:write name="record" property="commentText" /></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

commentText is of type string and the value is retreived from the database. If the `commentText contains http` i need to display it `as hyper link`.

```
Is it possible to represent the plain text that commentText holds completely as html ?
```

Any ideas are welcome,

Thanks

Comment: The simplest but may not be the efficient way is to extract the text of that property. Check if it contains http or other protocol, and accordingly display it on the UI.

Comment: Can you put a hyperlink tag (with correct syntax) when the text is returned by the getter method of that property?

Comment: say the property has the value MSIE: http://goo.gl/PIqF6 Chrome: http://goo.gl/xz9wX, in this case how to make hyperlinks ?

Comment: just as the way it has changed in the above comment

Comment: @SrikanthSridhar Are you going to update it later..? or you want it for display Use Simply <html:link> tag instead

Comment: @Pragnani I didn't understand. I tried this way <html:link paramId="i" paramName="record" paramProperty="commentText"> ?

Comment: @SrikanthSridhar why are you using Bean:Write..? I am clear to you brother, if you want to update the text later than you are allowed to use it, but showing a link <html:link > will be enough

Comment: @Pragnani, <html:link> is not working for me. I am using bean:write to print the property value. As you said i just need to display it as hyperlink if the string has http link.

Comment: @SrikanthSridhar Take a hidden variable save the value in it, print it using out.print() in your jsp, check in the jsp page whether it contains http or not if it contains http then  surround Anchor(<a>) tag

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26216/discussion-between-srikanth-sridhar-and-pragnani)